# How to dispaly the image without stretching with specific size

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application. In that i want to display the image. And the available space is `1000X500`.
Now i have to check that image width and height more than that size or not. I did that one and if the size is more than `1000X500` then i set that image size to that size.

My problem is if that image size is less than `1000X500` then i want to increase the size of that image.If i increase the size then image will be stretched.So i want to increase the size and find-out the exact size for that image.

And set that image to that exact size.And also i have to maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: You want to avoid image distortion while stretching?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748198/uiimageview-not-resizing-when-bounds-or-frame-is-changed/11964531#11964531